# Why my e-mails from my digital ocean server are going to spam

Tags: php, apache, email, digital-ocean, postfix-mta

I am hosting my website on digital ocean and using LAMP stack. I am using postfix to send e-mails. My all e-mails are going to gmail spam folders, I am using proper headers when sending from php mail() function still mails are going to spam folders. I have found this is due to dns entries but I have made all the entries i.e spf, dmarc, dkim and I have added my domain name in mx entry.

Can anyone help me out in solving this?

Comment: There may be any number of contributing factors to the spam score of your message, in particular when dealing with a big operator like Gmail or Outlook. These tend to be a little more strict in general. Have you checked the reputation of your IP? Are you making sure your message isn't spammy at all? You may want to test your message's spam score, for which there are a number of free tools available.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I have checked with mail tester and I have found that my mails are not spam,  my mail score is good.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I have checked with https://www.mail-tester.com/ and found my email score to be 9/10 and they say below 5 mails are considered as spam

Comment: Check Gmal's recommendations  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en briefly: SPF + DKIM + DMARC